# How to label encode a attribute in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

**Example :**

**Assume an attribute Result**

**Result**

| M |

| B |

| B |

| M |

**Into**

**Result**

| 0 |

| 1 |

| 1 |

| 0 |

*To achieve this without using LabelEncoder or OneHotEncoding. Like Is there any possible way to do it with the python dictionary?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a dictionary to map the values to new labels and use the map() method to label encode the attributes.

something like:

```
df['result'].map(mapping_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'result': 'M'}, {'result':'B'}, {'result':'B'}, {'result':'M'}])
# Sol 1
def changeValue(r):
    if r == 'M':
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

df.apply(lambda x: changeValue(x['result']), axis=1)
# Sol 2
# df['result'].map({'M': 0, 'B': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
f, _ = pd.factorize(df['Result'])
df['Result'] = f
print(df)
>>>

  Result
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   0
```